# Can I jump to the previous/next keyframe but ignore Grease Pencil keyframes?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, timeline

I'm using a shortcut for the *Jump to previous/next keyframe* function, but when the scene's *Grease Pencil* is visible, *Grease Pencil's* keyframes are also in the timeline.

It interferes in jumping between keyframes of an object I am animating.

When I turn off *Grease Pencil*, the keyframe markers disappear. I can jump to only my object's keyframes again, but I lose the scene's *Grease Pencil* in the viewport.

So, I want to see the scene's *Grease Pencil* in the viewport but not see it's keyframes in the timeline.

Are there options to enable this?

Answer (score 1):

By default blender 2.8 doesnt show greasepencil keyframes in the timeline viewer.

I found out in [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/show-grease-pencil-keyframes-alongside-all-other-keyframes/1159407)  that the keyframes a bit iffy on greasepencil in 2.8 but if you want to see them use the dopesheet instead of the timeline as the keyframe viewer. You can use up/down arrow keys to navigate between keyframes there.

You can do a dual split to have both dopesheets or a dopesheet/timeline to see both.

- If your selected on a GreasePencil object... up/down will go through GP keyframes
- If selected on a regular dopesheet object (e.g. mesh , curve etc...) up/down will go through normal frames.

[image]